# How many meters is it/are there/is there between?

Tags: dummy-pronouns

Which one is correct?

> 1 How many meters is it between this tree and that car?
>
> 2 How many meters is there between this tree and that car?
>
> 3 How many meters are there between this tree and that car?

Answer (score 2):

'Is' is the singular form of the verb to be, and 'are' is the plural form.

1 How many meters **is** it between this tree and that car? - correct, the distance ('it') is a singular thing.

2 How many meters **is** there between this tree and that car? - incorrect, the metres/meters are plural.

3 How many meters **are** there between this tree and that car? - correct, see 2 above.

Comment: OK. But "10 meters is not a long distance" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

All three sentences are correct in terms of word usage and subject-verb agreement but have slightly different meanings.

The first two sentences are using the singular form of the verb *to be* (meaning **is**) in regard to *the distance*, which is implied by the word (**it**) and *the space* which is implied by the word (**there**). Distance and space are singular nouns and are in agreement with their verb form.

The third sentence is using the plural form of the verb (meaning **are**) in regard to the word meters, which is also plural. So here too, subject-verb agreement is correct.